# Как добавить строку средствами SDK к существующим ресурсам?

Tags: android, apk, resources

Пытаюсь добавить новые ресурсы с помощью aapt в ранее скомпилированный проект для Android. Xml, layit, assets спокойно добавляются через aapt a file.apk xml/file.xml  Всё работает.
А как добавить строки из value/Strings? Вариант декомпиляции и мержа двух xml с строками, не подходит. Очень долго. Хочется что бы было не затратно по времени. И нативно. Как я понимаю строки хранятся в resource.rsc. Существуют ли документация по его редактированию?

Comment: В чем цель такого добавления? Чтобы ресурсы использовались нужно их id, сгенерированный во время компиляции, подставить в код, соответственно просто добавление строки в файл ресурсов ничего не дает

Comment: ID можно совершено спокойной добавляется вместе со строкой. Проблема будет при добавлении других ресурсов, тут действительно похоже без перекомпиляции не как. Но строки и xml из папки xml/*. точно можно просто добавить. Мне просто не хочется для этого добавлять в проект новый инструмент. Хочется это делать тем что есть в sdk. aapt самый близкий кандидат. Но пока не нашёл в документации такого.